# How can use SendDocumentAsync in telegram bot in c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm new in telegram bot,and I have read [this tutorial](https://mrroundrobin.github.io/telegram.bot/html/M_Telegram_Bot_TelegramBotClient_SendDocumentAsync_1.htm)

But I could not use that example in my code, I have html file on my server and want to send that with the telegram bot, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume theat you have set up your bot client successfully. Then you can send a (HTML-)document with the `SendDocumentAsync` like this:

```
private async void BotClientOnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a web request to download the html file from your server
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
    req.Method = "GET";

    using (var response = await req.GetResponseAsync())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        await BotClient.SendDocumentAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, new FileToSend("file.html", stream));
    }
}
```

The stream passed to the `FileToSend` is the content of the file.

However the file is not displayed as a Web page:

[image: The bot sent a file]

Comment: ok please wait to test that